# seaborn.FacetGrid on array of arrays

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm generating an array of arrays in a function, passing to a pandas.DataFrame and I want to run multiple histograms, for each array, to validate the data.

My df is like this, where the columns are arrays and rows the specific indexes. Its built using `pd.DataFrame(np.array(nodeRemovals).T)` (but I tried without the transpose).

```
       0     1
0   1257  2112
1   2527  1455
2    298    58
3   1762   155
4   1472  1695
5   1563  1327
6   2018  2589
7   1540  1104
8   1014  1939
9   2662   984
10  2477   364
```

I thought of defining a custom map function, where one column would be selected, but based on the available documentation of [structured multi-plot grids](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/axis_grids.html) I couldn't figure it out.

Right now I'm doing, but it yields no histogram mosaic, as I wanted.

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(nodeDf)
g.map(sns.histplot,  kde=True, bins=10, color='blue')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I load the data of yours

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
a = """       0     1
0   1257  2112
1   2527  1455
2    298    58
3   1762   155
4   1472  1695
5   1563  1327
6   2018  2589
7   1540  1104
8   1014  1939
9   2662   984
10  2477   364"""
df_wide= pd.read_fwf(StringIO(a),colspecs=[(4,10),(10,16)])
```

I call this format "wide" because you have one column per source array, potentially being a "wide" dataframe. We will now convert it into a "long" dataframe, where all data is stacked vertically instead. That is the format that seaborn is best designed to work with. Sure, it can do with wide data, but I think you get less problems and misunderstandings in long form. See more in their documentation https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/data_structure.html#long-form-vs-wide-form-data

```py
df_long = df_wide.melt(var_name = 'array',value_name='removals')
```

Finally, we use seaborn to plot. To make a grid of histograms, you can either go the route of `FacetGrid` as you did, but there is a convenience function that does exactly that. It is called `displot`

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.displot(data=df_long,x='removals',col='array',color='blue',kde=True,bins=10)
plt.show()
```

The result is like this

[image: Two histograms side by side]